# Bitronix Transaction not working with JMS queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jms, bitronix

I have a objective of using Bitronix transaction where i should use two resources:

1. Database
2. JMS

I have the following java code:

```
package com.mycompany.app;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueBrowser;
import javax.jms.QueueReceiver;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.transaction.TransactionManager;
import javax.transaction.UserTransaction;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.transaction.Transaction;
import org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager;

import bitronix.tm.BitronixTransactionManager;
import bitronix.tm.TransactionManagerServices;

public class JMSExample {

    static String serverUrl = "tcp://localhost:61616"; // values changed
    static String userName = "admin";
    static String password = "admin";

    static TextMessage message;

    public static void sendTopicMessage(String topicName, String messageStr) {

        Connection connection = null;

        try {
            BitronixTransactionManager btm = TransactionManagerServices.getTransactionManager();
            btm.begin();
            System.out.println("Publishing to destination '" + topicName + "'\n");
            ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(serverUrl);
            connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
            Session session = connection.createSession(true, Session.SESSION_TRANSACTED);
            Queue queue = session.createQueue(topicName);
            Message msg = session.createTextMessage(messageStr);
            msg.setJMSCorrelationID("correlationID1");
            MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
            producer.send(msg);
            System.out.println("Published message: " + messageStr);
            session.commit();
            session.close();
            connection.close();
            btm.rollback();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JMSExample.sendTopicMessage("test", "Hi");
    }
}
```

When I run the above program I am able to see the messages in the queue.
But I want the JMS transaction to get nested along with the Bitronix transaction. In other words, if the Bitronix rolls back there shouldn't be any messages in the queue as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to work atomically with 2 resources in a transaction then you need to acquire [`javax.transaction.xa.XAResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAResource.html) implementations from each resource manager (i.e. the JMS broker and the database). Once you have those you can enlist them in the JTA transaction you've started with the transaction manager. Then any commit or roll-back will be performed atomically with the enlisted XA resources.

To get an `XAResource` from JMS take a look at [`javax.jms.XAConnectionFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/XAConnectionFactory.html). You can use `createXAConnection()` to get an instance of [`javax.jms.XAConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/XAConnection.html) and then use `createXASession()` to get an [`javax.jms.XASession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/XASession.html) and then finally use `getXAResource()`.

To get an `XAResource` from JDBC take a look at [`javax.sql.XADataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/XADataSource.html). You can use `getXAConnection()` to get an instance of [`javax.sql.XAConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sql/XAConnection.html) and then use `getXAResource()`.

Then you can call [`getTransaction()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html#getTransaction--) on the transaction manager and use the returned [`javax.transaction.Transaction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html) to invoke [`enlistResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html#enlistResource-javax.transaction.xa.XAResource-) with your XAResources. Then when you call `commit()` or `rollback()` the transaction manager will deal with all your `XAResource` implementations and ensure everything is performed atomically.

Answer (score 0):

Removing session.commit() while btm.rollback() did the job

Comment: I don't think this is a solution to your problem. Removing the commit() just means that the message won't be sent regardless of whether or not the Bitronix transaction is rolled back.